# Querying data in pandas where points are grouped by a hexbin function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, seaborn

Both seaborn and pandas provide APIs in order to plot bivariate histograms as a hexbin plot (example plotted below). However, I am searching to execute a query for the points that are located in the same hexbin. Is there a function to retrieve the rows associated with the data points in the hexbin?

The give an example:
My data frame contains 3 rows: `A`, `B` and `C`. I use `sns.jointplot(x=A,y=B)` to plot the density. Now, I want to execute a query on each data point located in the same bin. For instance, for each bin compute the mean of the `C` value associated with each point.

[image]

Comment: You can *plot* the mean. Is that what you mean? From a plot you can of course also retrieve the data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I am not interested in plotting values, but rather "converting" the raw dataframe to a dataframe where each row represents a hexbin where the columns include values based on some processing did on the raw values in that hexbin.

Comment: I'm not aware of any helper functions that would operate on hexagonal grids. The [matplotlib hexbin source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/8466da0a120151a1840b39a3ffc23220b8d24ee7/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L4527) is pretty low-level. Of course one could copy it to implement something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Current solution -- Quick Hack**

Currently, I have implemented the following function to apply a function to the data associated with a (x,y) coordinate located in the same hexbin:

```
def hexagonify(x, y, values, func=None):

    hexagonized_list = []

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_visible(False)
    if func is not None:
        image = plt.hexbin(x=x, y=y, C=values, reduce_C_function=func)
    else:
        image = plt.hexbin(x=x, y=y, C=values)

    values = image.get_array()

    verts = image.get_offsets()
    for offc in range(verts.shape[0]):
            binx, biny = verts[offc][0], verts[offc][1]
            val = values[offc]
            if val:
                hexagonized_list.append((binx, biny, val))

    fig.clear()
    plt.close(fig)
    return hexagonized_list
```

The values (with the same size as x or y) are passed through the `values` parameter. The hexbins are computed through the `hexbin` function of `matplotlib`. The values are retrieved through the `get_array()` function of the returned `PolyCollection`. By default, the `np.mean` function is applied to the accumalated values per bin. This functionality can be changed by providing a function to the `func` paramater. Subsequently, the `get_offsets()` method allows us to calculate the center of the bins ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951065/get-bins-coordinates-with-hexbin-in-matplotlib)). In this way, we can associate (by default) mean value of the provided values per hexbin. However, this solution is a hack, so any improvements to this solution are welcome.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant with [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130442/querying-data-in-pandas-where-points-are-grouped-by-a-hexbin-function#comment95095163_54131950) below the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### From `matplotlib`

If you have already drawn the plot, you can get Bin Counts from [`polycollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hexbin.html) returned by `matplotlib`:

> polycollection: A PolyCollection instance; use PolyCollection.get_array on this to get the counts in each hexagon.

This functionality is also available in:

- [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html);
- [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html);

#### Pure `pandas`

Here a MCVE using only `pandas` that can handle the `C` property:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Trial Dataset:
N=1000
d = np.array([np.random.randn(N), np.random.randn(N), np.random.rand(N)]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['x', 'y', 'c'])

# Create bins: 
df['xb'] = pd.cut(df.x, 3)
df['yb'] = pd.cut(df.y, 3)

# Group by and Aggregate:
p = df.groupby(['xb', 'yb']).agg('mean')['c']
p.unstack()
```

First we create bins using [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html). Then we [group by and aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). You can pick the `agg` function you like to aggregate `C` (eg. `max`, `median`, etc.).

The output is about:

```
yb               (-2.857, -0.936]  (-0.936, 0.98]  (0.98, 2.895]
xb                                                              
(-2.867, -0.76]          0.454424        0.519920       0.507443
(-0.76, 1.34]            0.535930        0.484818       0.513158
(1.34, 3.441]            0.441094        0.493657       0.385987
```

Comment: Of course plotting something and then deleting the plot to only keep the data is a ugly, but easy option.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, added shortcut

Comment: How would I be able to get the associated C column values from that polycollection? I understand only the count can be extracted from the hexbins, not the x and y values of the points in the specific hexbins?

Comment: This  approach does not use the hexbins but instead will use rectangular or in your case square bins.